# Inconsistent behavior for firebase friendslist

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently trying to setup a friendslist relationship using Firebase and I'm experiencing some issues with the process of adding a friend for a user.

I currently have a schema like this:

```
    users                                                           
    -----                                                  
    UID                                                    
     ->Name                                            
     ->Friendslist
       ->UID of friend:true

    userDisplays
    ------------
    -Users Name:Users UID

    addedFriends
    ------------
    -UID of added user
     ->UID Of user that did the adding
```

My idea of adding a friend is using the name of the user and looking them up in the `userDisplays` tree, that lookup seems to work everytime. However, when I then try to read the uid value from the child in `userDisplays` it will sometimes return NULL, or will skip the adding entirely after it finds the uid value (by this I mean it will not add the uid to the adding user and not create a `addedFriends` child).

The same issue is when the adding user successfully adds the desired user and a `addedFriends` child is created linking the two, but again when the added user checks for recent addings and is given the option to 'add back' it will return NULL or skip the removal of the `addedFriends` child and not add the uid to the users list of friends.

I tried to copy the relationship example found in the docs, but I'm confused on where I am missing things, or if this is expected behavior?

Here is my structure after two users have been created. Before a friends list has been created.

```
    {
     "userDisplays" : {
       "a" : "fed7738e-7dec-4ff3-9cc9-46dee3c189e6",
       "t" : "c3b27833-d56b-40e9-b46f-c99128193f3d"
     },

    "users" : {
       "c3b27833-d56b-40e9-b46f-c99128193f3d" : {
       "displayName" : "t",
       "email" : "test@test.com",
       "provider" : "password"
     },
      "fed7738e-7dec-4ff3-9cc9-46dee3c189e6" : {
      "displayName" : "a",
      "email" : "test2@test.com",
      "provider" : "password"
    }
 }
}
```

This is the swift code I'm using to perform the adding of a friend given a user name:

```
ref.userDisplayBaseSingleton.childByAppendingPath("/\(userName)").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if snapshot.value is NSNull{
                print("null")
            }else{
                print(snapshot.value)
                print("found val")
                ref.userBaseSingleton.childByAppendingPath(snapshot.value as! String).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snap) in

                    let friendData = [
                        snap.key:true
                    ]

                    ref.userBaseSingleton.childByAppendingPath("\(currentUser!.id!)/friends").updateChildValues(friendData)

                    let currentAddData = [
                        snap.key:currentUser!.id!
                    ]

                    let friendAddRef = ref.addBaseSingleton.childByAutoId()
                    friendAddRef.setValue(currentAddData)

                })
            }
        })
```

Basically the issues I'm experiencing from this snippet is that sometimes the look up from userDisplays doesn't return a value, or if it does it doesn't add a `addedFriends` node. I've experienced a bug when retrying adding the username again, but it will actually generate a new uid of the `users` and then generate a new `addedFriends` child.

For example, if I was user `t` and I tried to add `a` a few kinds of behavior can happen.

1. userDisplay for `a` returns `null`
2. userDisplay returns `a` and returns a's `uid` but the `addedFriends` node isn't generated
3. `a` is properly added, and an `addedFriends` node is generated, however when `user a` is notified of the add and is given the option to add back `t` it seems to reproduce the same kind of errors.
4. I've noticed that after a period of time, the actual `uid` of `t` will update on the firebase and then the add will be successful. By this I mean that the initial `uid` that `t` is assigned will change and then I've noticed the code above will work. I'm also assuming the reason why its updated has to do with the errors thats happening, but I could be wrong.

Heres a snippet of the error happening

```
}
   {
  "addedFriends" : {
    "-KH6pR5TV7vjVeADc7mc" : {
      "22a3c5fa-e578-4ada-b3c1-355add80041e" : "098804cd-1ffa-4508-b353-6f6a4377661f"
    }
  },
  "userDisplays" : {
    "test" : "f0bb77a9-8156-4d44-ad74-6d6b01765802",
    "test2" : "098804cd-1ffa-4508-b353-6f6a4377661f"
  },
  "users" : {
    "098804cd-1ffa-4508-b353-6f6a4377661f" : {
      "displayName" : "test2",
      "email" : "test2@test.com",
      "friends" : {
        "22a3c5fa-e578-4ada-b3c1-355add80041e" : true
      },
      "provider" : "password"
    },
    "f0bb77a9-8156-4d44-ad74-6d6b01765802" : {
      "displayName" : "test",
      "email" : "test@test.com",
      "provider" : "password"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you're trying to do. Can you add a minimal snippet of the actual JSON (as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button your Firebase dashboard) and the code that reproduces the problem? Such an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) makes it a lot easier to see what you've done, where you got stuck or made a mistake and to show you how to progress.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've added some more code and tried to be more specific about the issues I'm experiencing with it. Let me know if anything else needs to be clarified.

Comment: You may have overcomplicated what you are trying to do. If user a is trying to add user b as a friend, user a would generally select user b from a list. In that case the list would probably be displayed in a tableView with a datasource. That datasource (typically an array) would have the users that can be added as well as their uid. When user a selects the user, grab the uid from the array and setValue to store it. On there other hand, if you are going to perform some kind of query, that query could/would return the node of the user you want to add, which would include the uid. Yes? No?

Comment: Sure, the process of adding the user directly to the friends list is fairly straight forward. However, even adding the uid into a list for the user doesn't seem to be the correct one (the one in friends is different than the actual user). So even without the `addedFriends` node. It doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to implement the feature of allowing the added friend to see a alert of the friend that added them with the ability to return add them back (like snapchat).

Comment: Turns out the issue was due to me enabling disk persistence but not deleting the app when testing and only the server side code ;( lots of egg on my face